# symfony: Own cache class for config cache

Tags: caching, symfony1, config, factories

I was just able to write my own view cache class and activate it over factories.yml.
Now I'm wondering how I can do the same for the config cache.

**Edit:** Fist I thought symfony will automatically use the caching method I choosed for view cache, but it doesn't.

**Solution:**

It's not very clean but it works. I extended the sfApplicationConfiguration and replaced it. Then I overwrote the method getConfigCache(). Here I replaced sfConfigCache with my sfConfigBlobCache.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this chapter](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/14-Playing-with-Symfony-Config-Cache#chapter_14_custom_config_handlers).

Comment: Thx for the link, but I can't find a ready to use example which shows for instance how to use mysql for config caching instead of the default file cache.